# How to pass the data present in the class to server in the TCP/IP model?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm working on TCP/IP model, following is my class declaration:

```
class searchword
{
        std::string word;
        std::map<int,int> wordcout;
        int totalcout;
        // Some functions that processes the data and fill the above
        // data member.
};
```

Now I want to send this data (i.e. this class has) to server in TCP/IP client-server model.
How I can do that, should I declare a friend method into this class that send the data or is there any other approach?

Note: I have created vector of object of this class. I want to send the data for all objects

Comment: Read about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), and about libraries such as [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is there any other way? because I'm new to TCP/IP programming. or can you provide me some code snippet for this?

Comment: This is not a trivial question, if you are in a client-server model, you have 2 programs, so the code of your server does not share the code of your client they cannot communicate as easily as you might think